# creating jar file in Maven based on package wise

Tags: java, maven, jar

i need to create the jar files based on the package wise, for example,  the package structure is like

```
com.A
com.B
com.C
```

I need to create the jar file A.jar, B.jar, C.jar.can anyone please tell how to do this in maven?

Answer (score 3):

You can define different executions of the Maven JAR plugin (each for the `jar` goal and the `package` phase). Each of these (three additional) executions for A, B and C would override the following configuration parameters:

- Include only desired package. Set `includes.include` to something like `com/A/**`
- Set the appropriate output name. Set `finalName` to something like `${project.build.finalName}-A`

All that being said, though, you may also want to consider breaking up your project into three separate projects A, B and C instead. That way you'll follow standard Maven, instead of configuring the above, because, although it may work, it is not very common. And Maven prefers convention over configuration.

Comment: I second the breaking up!